# Sorting in an cl_gui_alv_grid by column?

Tags: sorting, abap, alv

I'm generating an internal table with `cl_gui_alv_grid` that has five columns and I can't seem to figure out how to sort by column 1 once the table is loaded. I managed to do it with `cl_salv_table`, however not with the grid. Any idea please? I suppose it's done somehow with the `CALL METHOD go_alv->set_sort_criteria` however I'm getting a crash when triggering the table view.

```
DATA: lt_sort TYPE lvc_t_sort,
      ls_sort TYPE lvc_s_sort.
```

```
FORM sort_data.
   REFRESH: lt_sort.
   CLEAR: ls_sort.
   ls_sort-spos = '1'.
   ls_sort-fieldname = 'Column1'.
   ls_sort-up        = abap_true.
   APPEND ls_sort TO lt_sort.
ENDFORM.
```

```
FORM first_display.
   PERFORM sort_data.
   CALL METHOD go_alv->set_table_for_first_display
   EXPORTING
      i_structure_name = 'TABLE_STRUCTURE'
      is_layout        = gs_layout
   CHANGING
      it_outtab        = gt_salv_table
ENDFORM.
```

```
CALL METHOD go_alv->set_sort_criteria
    EXPORTING
      it_sort = lt_sort
*    EXCEPTIONS
*     no_fieldcatalog_available = 1
*     others  = 2.
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and provide the exact symptoms of the crash. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Do you call the *set_sort_criteria* before the *set_table_for_first_display*? It looks like there is no fieldcatalouge yet, this is why it does not work.

I think more straighforward is: The *set_table_for_first_display* method has a changing parameter it_sort, just use that one for importing the sort table into the class, no need to call *set_sort_criteria*:

```
   CALL METHOD go_alv->set_table_for_first_display
   EXPORTING
      i_structure_name = 'TABLE_STRUCTURE'
      is_layout        = gs_layout
   CHANGING
      it_outtab        = gt_salv_table
      it_sort          = lt_sort
   EXCEPTIONS
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it gives me an error that field catalog is not available...Is it necessary to have one in this case?

Comment: @smoothlikebutter Not "in this case", the field catalog is mandatory in **all** cases. Even when you don't sort. So, I advise that you test with very simple program before including more complex feature like the sorting, that's the way to do when you have problems. For more information, see how to do in [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @smoothlikebutter Having a field catalog is necessary. You can easily generate one with FM LVC_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE.